# Angular2: Using environment variables in index.html

Tags: angular, environment-variables

Any ideas on how to use environment variables in the `index.html` file. I need to include `.js script` A if the environment is prod and script B if the environment is anything else. Otherwise I will need to manually change the `index.html` file before deployment.

Comment: maybe this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45467062/4908847