# How can I access environment constants from index.html in Angular 4?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to setup a small thing, and I need to check if my current environment is PROD, and I need to do it on my `index.html`. How can I access the `environment` const? Right now it shows as undefined.

Comment: You can't access environment variables using Angular during runtime. Are you using the Angular CLI? If so you can specify at build time what environment variables to pass to Angular.

Comment: oh but index.html is the only file that isn't built in an Angular way, so I'm not sure it's possible to access environment.ts from there. Maybe some gulp script to embed the environment variable in the index.html

Comment: Oh, got it! Nice idea about the gulp script! And yes, I'm using Angular Cli!

Comment: @LuizMitidiero I encountered the same trouble. How do you handle this?

Comment: @niaomingjian it's like Simon said before, the Index.html is the unique file which isn't built in an Angular way, so you have to use something like Gulp, or some npm task which does that for you first.

Comment: maybe this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45467062/4908847

Comment: The most relevant answer I've seen about this is to create index.html files for each (or some) environments and replace the default with the environment specific file (in the angular.json file). I don't like this approach but it should work. But... I think its Angular 6+.

Answer (score 0):

after two years you might have found a way out but for someone how might need this try the following logic

set the environment on application load by setting the value to ie localStorage / sessionStorage and then read the localStorage/sessionStorage from javascript

for example

```
localStorage.setItem("app_enviroment" , environment.app_enviroment);
```

[image]

Edit:
l have been keeping my config on environment.ts
you can config it for different environments ie
environment.prod.ts
environment.stage.ts

so basically on build you decide which one to use

Comment: This is a bad idea. Env variables are meant to be kept secret!

Comment: @itsHarshad localStorage is not safe for sensitive stuff, l use environment have updated the answer  but l believe nothing about sensitivity (its just sort of a flag )was mentioned don't know why the downvote if sensitivity wasn't asked in question but l have updated those, thanks for the feedback

Comment: I think you should mention in your answer that if you just want to store a flag, why do you need environment variables? You can simple store them in localStorage. Taking off my downvote considering you'll mention this in your answer. Have a great day. :)